# Is an expression involving function type an lvalue or an rvalue?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

```
void fn() {}
void (&lref)() = fn;
void (&&rref)() = fn;

int main() {}
```

Compiles well under g++ 4.8.1.

So, `fn` is an expression, and an expression must have a category according to the ISO standard.

Which **category** does the expression belong to before any automatic type promotion is performed (since both references can accept the result of evaluating the expression `fn`)?

Comment: From N4296 section 3.10, an lvalue designates a function or an object. An rvalue is, among other things, a value that is not associated with an object. So, `fn` is a function, and so, an lvalue. And, `fn` evaluates to a value that is not associated with an object (cf. Section 1.8: a function is not an object), and so, an rvalue. Is that the way it is?

Comment: I don't think a function is a value. The standard only uses the term "value" when talking about objects and object types.

Comment: But, an expression must assume exactly one category. So, `fn` must either be an lvalue or an rvalue, not both. So, the expression `fn` is an lvalue or an rvalue?

Comment: @Angew: If I buy that (i.e., the expression `fn` is an lvalue), why `void (&&rref)() = fn;` compiles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per C++11 3.10/1, a function is always an lvalue. So the expression `fn` is an lvalue.

According to 8.5.3/5, correctly typed functions can be used to initialise rvalue references:

> - Otherwise, the reference shall be an lvalue reference to a non-volatile const type (i.e., *cv1* shall be `const`), **or the
>     reference shall be an rvalue reference.**
>
>   - If the initializer expression
>
>     - is an xvalue, class prvalue, array prvalue or **function lvalue** and “*cv1* `T1`” is reference-compatible with “*cv2* `T2`”,
>         or
>     - ...
>
>     then the reference is bound to the value of the initializer expression in the first case ...

(Shortened, emphasis mine)